# Basic jQuery syntax question (optimization)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .js file with many functions all applied to one page. I'm trying to optimize my jQuery code to reduce the loading time.

Many of the functions are defined this way :

```
$(document).on( "change", ".fields-abc", function () { ... });
$(document).on( "change", ".fields-xyz", function () { ... });
```

Since these functions target fields located in the same div#myid, I could improve loading time by including #myid in the selector :

```
$(document).on( "change", "#myid .fields-abc", function () { ... });
$(document).on( "change", "#myid .fields-xyz", function () { ... });
```

But I suppose it would be even better if #myid was in a variable, then i target this variable in all the different functions?

If this is indeed better, how do I modify the syntax to target this variable ?
Like this ?

```
var myidvariable = $("#myid");    
$(document).find(myidvariable).on( "change", "#myid .fields-abc", function () { ... });
$(document).find(myidvariable).on( "change", "#myid .fields-xyz", function () { ... });
```

I suppose not...

Comment: Always use the closest parent for event delegation. If the elements are all a child of `#myid` then don't add the event handler on the `document` -> `$("#myid").on("change", ".fields-abc", ...)`

Comment: *I could improve loading time* - the change to the filter `selector` parameter of the `.on` is unlikely to have any impact on "loading time" - it's only used when the event fires. It *might* have a miniscule impact on execution time as the event bubbles up to the document, but for that to have *any impact* you'd have to be changing 1000s of fields and they'd have to be 1000s of levels deep in your html hierarchy.  Don't micro-optimise (nano-optimise!) before there's an actual  problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, you are right, but my example wasn't the best one. I actually have a lot of functions fired on page ready, and they are the one that cause problems since they are not well written.

Comment: "* I actually have a lot of functions fired on page ready, and they are the one that cause problems since they are not well written.*" then it doesn't sound like changing a selector would make that much of a difference. How about you improve the functions themselves?

Comment: As @VLAZ points out above, the answers have targeted what you've provided in the question.  It's likely there's a bigger picture - as alluded to with the later-comment of *actually have a lot of functions* - and your efforts would likely be better served identifying exactly which parts of your code could do with improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Always add event to closes static element. So if you do not replace `#myid` programmatically, then target it and chain your calls.

```js
$('#myid')
    .on('change', '.fields-abc', function () {})
    .on('change', '.fields-xyz', function () {})
```

---

Please note that if you have `var parent = $('#myid')` and `.fields-*` are also static, then you can pass element to look for element as second parameter to jQuery constructor

```js
var parent = $('#myid');

$('.fields-abc', parent).change(function () {})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to optimize to reduce loading time

The slowest part of your code, with respect to loading times, is the initial selector

```
$(document)
```

The `selector` parameter of the event will not impact loading times as it's just a string and won't be used to initialise the event.

So the best way to optimise your code is to reduce the occurrences of `$(selector)`,  in your case you can do either:

```
var doc = $(document);
doc.on("change", ".abc", ...);
doc.on("change", ".xyz", ...);
```

or make use of jquery's *chaining*:

```
$(document)
    .on("change", ".abc", ...)
    .on("change", ".xyz", ...);
```

(note the `;` only after the second `.on()`)

---

As noted, you can use a "closer" element, but the same principle applies, rather than:

```
$("#id").on(..);
$("#id").on(..);
```

chain the DOM query

```
$("#id").on(..).on(..);
```

Comment: thank you very much ! I'll look into that. When i look at my 2000 lines long code full of functions and the way i wrote them im sure i can reduce the loading time from 10 seconds to 2 pretty easily thanks to your advices :)

Comment: You may find that simply putting your event initialisers `$(...).on(...` inside a [doc.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) will substantially improve the *appearance of performance* for the user.

Comment: My JS document starts with : 

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

Is it what you mean ?

Comment: "*The slowest part of your code, with respect to loading times, is the initial selector*" I don't think cacheing the `$(document)` call would lead to any measurable change in execution time. Do you have any evidence it does?

Comment: @VLAZ every call to `$()` has *some* overhead and a DOM query has some more overhead, so not making those call reduces that overhead.  As mentioned, it's likely micro-optimisation, but seems OP has enough of them to make it worthwhile considering.   OP is attempting to optimise the `selector` part which has no impact on *loading* times, so clarifying which part is the slowest part of the provided code.

Comment: "*very call to $() has some overhead*" I'm asking is it measurable. If the difference is 0.0001ms vs 0.0005ms, does it really matter?

Comment: *does it matter* - no, that's what micro-optimisation means.

Comment: A micro-optimisation *might* matter. Depends on the context. Micro-optimising a trigonometry function might be crucial to a flight navigation system that uses it thousands of times a second to make sure the aircraft doesn't crash. Micro-optimisation means optimising something very small already, not "it's useless". It just happens that a lot of times a micro-optimisation is not worth it because it is not the real bottleneck of a system. Improving from 0.01ms to 0.1ms is a tenfold improvement but there might be another piece of code that runs for 1s vastly overshadowing the gain there.

Comment: @VLAZ not highly scientific, but confirming (not that it really needs it) that there is *some* overhead: https://jsfiddle.net/xn6zcr9k/   the point of this answer is that there *is* a difference between doing something and doing nothing, no matter how small.   OP was looking at optimising the "does nothing" part (the string in the "selector" field of `on`) and the answer should be taken in context.   The *slowest part* is still slower.  Any "measurable change" is irrelevant, it's still *slower*.

Comment: Yes, I didn't intend to dismiss micro-optimisation as something never worth doing.